# Creating sql table and reading values inside json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, database, presto

I have written a query that generates table based from a json file. The json file has a subsection that is json array and I can't seem to get my table to pick up the values from the json array.

Here an example of the json I am trying to create table from:

```
{"student": "1", "ai": [{"grade": "a", "term": 1}, {"grade": "b", "term": 2}], "year": "2017"}
```

Table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student(
  student string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  grade string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  term string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  year string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION 'students.json'
```

I also tried doing `ai.grade` but that didn't help.

The current output I am getting is:
    student      grade      term      year
    1                                 2017
    1                                 2017

What I want is:

```
student      grade      term      year
1            a          1         2017
1            b          2         2017
```

Please see [picture](https://ibb.co/1sG0Lcx) as the structure above is not showing probably.

Comment: Did you try mapping `ai` column to array of a row of "grade" and "term"?  In Hive syntax it would be something like `Array<struct<grade:string,term:string>>`.

Comment: Hadn't tried this, it seem to work but it doesn't output the results separately as I want instead it shows them in just one like ```[{grade=a, term=1}, {grade=b, term=2}]```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able create the table using this Hive syntax:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE student(
  student string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  ai array<struct<grade:string,tinyint>> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  year tinyint COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION 'students.json'
```

Once you have the table, you can use the following Presto query, which does an [`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) of the array into columns.  Note the `WITH` clause in the example query is provided only to simulate the `student` table above, and should be removed once you have the `student` table created.

```sql
WITH student AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS student,
        CAST(ARRAY[ROW('a', 1), ROW('b', 2)] AS ARRAY(ROW(grade VARCHAR, term TINYINT))) AS ai,
        2017 AS year
)
SELECT student, grade, term, year 
FROM student 
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ai)
```

```
 student | grade | term | year 
---------+-------+------+------
       1 | a     |    1 | 2017 
       1 | b     |    2 | 2017 
(2 rows)
```